# Check matrix size with potential trailing singleton dimension in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to verify (in a function), that the size of a matrix `A` is `a x b x c`, where potentially `c=1`.

So far I had:

```
if size(A) ~= [ a b c ]
    error('bad size');
end
```

However, if `c=1` (and `A` has the desired size):

```
size(A) = [ a b ]
```

since `size` removes trailing singleton dimensions. Therefore, the comparison will result in an error, as the vectors (`[a b]` and `[a b c]`) do not have the same size.

Is there anything nicer than

```
if c == 1 && size(A) ~= [ a b ] || c ~= 1 && size(A) ~= [ a b c ]
    error('bad size');
end
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[validateattributes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/validateattributes.html) does the job:

```
 validateattributes(A, {'numeric'}, {'size', [ a b c ]});
```

will not fail if `c=1` and `A` has the correct dimensions.

Comment: Wasn't this your own question? :D

Comment: Yes, just found the answer afterwards. validateattributes is definitely the better way to do what I want as it also generates the error messages and verifies the types (some custom classes are involved).

Comment: @jucestain I should wait 48h to do that. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/

Answer (score 1):

The output of `size(A)` varies with the manner in which it is invoked. For your case you could simply use:

```
[a1,b1,c1] = size(A);
if(any([a1,b1,c1]~=[ a b c ]))
    error('bad size');
end
```

Comment: Instead of `sum` you can write `any`.

Comment: @EitanT: Yeah, that would make much more sense. Thanks. Answer edited.

Comment: Thanks for that one. Funny, that upon assignment, we can add the additional element to the size vector.

Comment: Indeed. So will my first solution by the way.

Comment: @Memming: If `A` has more than 3 dimensions, the product of the last n-2 dimensions will simply be computed as `c1`. For example, if `A` is of size `1x2x3x4x5`, `a1 = 1`, `b1 = 2` and `c1 = 3*4*5`. This shouldn't be an issue though because @gzm0 only wanted to compare the size with `[a b c]`, which would be invalid if the compared vector were not of size `1x3`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution is this:

```
if (size(A) ~= [ a b c ](1:ndims(A)))
    error('bad size');
end
```

Which will work so long as A does not have more than 3 dimensions. If A does have more than 3 dimensions, then you're going to need to have a condition beforehand:

```
if (ndims(A)>3 || size(A)~=[a b c](1:ndims(A)))
    error('bad size');
end
```

Obviously, if the dimensions of A beyond the third one are singleton dimensions, this will consider it a bad size... but that may be acceptable.